# Why can't I understand this CSS calc() calculation? It literally makes my head hurt

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a CSS calculation that works to equally space children within a flexed container, with a predefined gap between them... The thing is, I just don't understand what's going on!

This has come about as I am wanting to create a SASS(SCSS) function to perform the calculation such that I can call it more easily and stop copy/pasting my long calculation.

The calculation is as such:

```
.my-class {
    --columns: 3;
    --gap: 16px;

    width: calc((1 / var(--columns) * 100%) - ((1 - 1 / var(--columns)) * var(--gap)));
}
```

I have created an example below to show the outcome when it is held within a fixed-width container (768px wide).

```css
.toCalc {
  --cols: 3;
  --gap: 16px;
  
  width: calc((1 / var(--cols) * 100%) - ((1 - 1 / var(--cols)) * var(--gap)));
  
  background: blue;
  height: 150px;
}

.container {
  width: 768px;
  height: 300px;
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  gap: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="toCalc">
    This is content
  </div>
  <div class="toCalc">
    This is content
  </div>
  <div class="toCalc">
    This is content
  </div>
</div>
```

My attempt to convert this to SCSS has not gone to plan:

```
@function calcWidth($cols, $gap) {
  @debug "1/cols: #{1/$cols}";
  @debug "(1/cols) * 100%: #{(1/$cols) * 100%}";
  @debug "1 - (1/cols): #{1 - (1/$cols)}";
  @debug "(1 - (1/cols)) * gap: #{(1 - (1/$cols)) * $gap}";

  $result = ((1/$cols) * 100%) - ((1 - (1/$cols)) * $gap);

  @debug "full result: #{$result}";

  @return $result;
}

...

.my-class {
  // Converted css properties (--var) to SCSS variables ($var)
  $cols: 3;
  $gap: 16px;

  width: calcWidth($cols, $gap);
}
```

With the values of `cols = 3` and `gap = 16px` as above, I get the debug messages:

```
DEBUG: 1/cols: 0.33333
DEBUG: (1/cols) * 100%: 33.33333%
DEBUG: 1 - (1/cols): 0.66667
DEBUG: (1 - (1/cols)) * gap: 10.66667px
DEBUG: full result: 22.66667px // <------------ This is not the same as we see?!
```

To me, the debug messages should be technically correct, working out the calculation from the brackets first...

Can anybody help me understand how the code gets us a width value of `245.33px` instead?

---

**Update**
It was pointed out that I had originally left the `%` out on the function calculation.

When adding this back in, I get the incompatibility message from SASS:

```
SassError: Incompatible units: 'px' and '%'.
```

Comment: Why don't you use CSS grid for that? It seems like a perfect fit.

Comment: `$result = ((1/$cols) * 100) - ((1 - (1/$cols)) * $gap);` You are missing the `%` sign after the 100

Comment: @Joe82 - My question wasn't about the best way to space things out in a grid...

Comment: @clod9353 I have added the % in and now I get the incompatibility message of SASS multiplying % and px together.

Comment: @physicsboy try wrapping everything into a `calc` function. So it would be:
`$result: calc(...)`

Comment: @physicsboy You also need to interpolate your variables inside you calc. So `$cols` should be `#{$cols}`, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both @clod9353 and a fresh pair of eyes in the morning, I found that by breaking the original into pieces and taking into a function that wrapping it within `calc()` got the result!

I did a lot of setting the width of my piece to the individual parts of the calculation just to get some numbers and of course, adding the `%` in did make the difference and help me to understand where I was getting confused.

Yes - This calculation will be based on the containing element width. Luckily I am using a fixed width container so this makes visualising the issue and getting hard numbers easier.

## Breakdown:

**Original calculation:** `1 / var(--cols) * 100%) - ((1 - 1 / var(--cols)) * var(--gap))`

For examples sake, let's take it that we are using 3 columns with a gap of 16px.

**First part:**

`1 / 3 * 100%` results in `33.333...%`

This means that our individual columns will of course be 1/3 of the width, but will now work as the value is represented as a percentage

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  width: calc(1/3*100%);
  height: 100px
}

.grey {
  background: lightgrey;
}

.blue {
  background: lightblue;
}

.green {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child grey">Some content</div>
  <div class="child blue">Some content</div>
  <div class="child green">Some content</div>
</div>
```

**Second part:**

`(1 - 1 / 3) * 16px`

This essentially indicates that we want to create a gap of 16px between all of the columns.

`1 - 1 / 3 = 2/3` - Indicates we want to apply a gap to 2 of the 3 columns.

```css
.container {
width: 500px;
height: 300px;
background: grey;
display: flex;
gap: 16px;
}

.child {
width: calc((1 / 3 * 100%) - ((1 - 1 / 3) * 16px));
height: 100px;
}

.grey {
background: lightgrey;
}

.blue {
background: lightblue;
}

.green {
background: lightgreen;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child grey">Some content</div>
  <div class="child blue">Some content</div>
  <div class="child green">Some content</div>
</div>
```